# Python - How to show missing datasets on my plot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plot

The legend on my plot shows various entries; however, I can only see one dataset actually plotted in the graph. How can I show the rest?

[image: House Price Index Data Plotted vs. Time]

The code that I am using is the following:

```
HPI_data = pd.read_pickle('pandas_pickle.pickle')

print(HPI_data.head())
#note: all data points are being printed correctly up to this point so I do not think that there is anything nothing wrong with the pickling.

HPI_data.plot()
plt.legend().remove()
plt.show()
# the plot only shows only dataset for some reason!
```

The following shows the actual output of print(HPI_data.head()):
[House pricing index raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTBX4.png)

The output displayed is exactly how I want to be; however, the issue I am dealing with is with the plotting.

Comment: Could be several things wrong.  We'd need to see data to tell for sure.

Comment: @piRSquared thanks for your quick response. I updated my post to show the data. Do you need any more information?

Comment: It is bad form to post a picture for data.  We want to see text or something else that we can actually import and play with.  We can't do that with images.  Fortunately, it was easy to see the problem.  It may be a surprise to you, but all of your columns are being shown.  But they are all identical and are right on top of one another.  You won't fix this problem unless your columns are actually differentiated.

Comment: @piRSquared noted. Will keep that in mind.Thanks for the tip. Also, thank you for pointing that out! Now I just have to figure out how that happened in the first place. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: @piRSquared i fixed the issue. Thank you so much for all your help! Much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm glad it worked out.